# primefaces poll component doesn't call the method 5.1

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using poll component of primefaces 5.1

I've jsf2 page like

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
      <ui:composition template="/templates/securedContent.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="content">


       <h:form id="form">
                <p:poll interval="1"
                    listener="#{counterView.increment}" update=":form" />
                <p:outputLabel value="#{counterView.number}" />
        </h:form>

      </ui:define>
      </ui:composition> 

     </html>
```

and the bean is :

```
package main.com.zc.project.presentation.attendance.bean;


import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CounterView implements Serializable {

   private int number;

   public int getNumber() {
       return number;
   }

   public void increment() {
       number++;
   }
}
```

I'm using primefaces 5.1 , and the poll doesn't call Bean method as expected could  anyone help me please?

Comment: _"and the poll doesn't call Bean method as expected"_ How do you know... What did you investigate?

Comment: I made debug on bean method , and no performing occures
but on client side as I made instead of listener >>> oncomplete= alert('hi') and the alert appears but method no

Comment: that is just a small part of debugging. Check the requests in the browser, etc..

Comment: 200 OK
POST http://localhost:8080/SurveyMaker/system/performedSurveys/survey.xhtml



<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="txt_count"><![CDATA[<span id="txt_count">0</span>]]></update>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[H4sIAAAAAAAAAM1XX2wURRifXnuUttgUKv9MS0opRE3d4+7656AgFFrk4lEIV6tAlM7tDndD9x8zs9ctCAkmaiIxmKgxJhhN9MEH8AVfeNEoMSYkEuWFRGKixsT4QEKMiTE
+6Mzs7d71buGOJ9iHvbmdb+b7fb/vz3xz8TaI2pSA5cdhESoOw7qyF9LCPmhHW3/86uqq2R+aQWQPaNctqO2BKrNIGrSxAkG0YOmaa
/5YJyJj4QAAA=]]></update></changes></partial-response

Comment: Well, something IS being called... Please create an [mcve] I see things in the update that are not in your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)